# How to send Alt+space to console window?

Tags: windows, console, wsh

```
import win32com.client
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.AppActivate("Command Prompt")
shell.SendKeys("%{ }")               # This
#shell.SendKeys("% ")                # and this
#shell.SendKeys("%( )")              # and this is not working
```

WScript is not mandatory, you can propose any programmatic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scan codes (56 and 57) are required:

```
from win32api import *
from win32con import *
keybd_event(VK_LMENU, 56, 0, 0)
keybd_event(VK_SPACE, 57, 0, 0)
keybd_event(VK_SPACE, 57, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
keybd_event(VK_LMENU, 56, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bug in windows. Here is an example where in notepad the "% " works and in CMD it does not:

```
    ' SendKeys.vbs  Example Script
    ' VBScript to send keyboard strokes to command prompt and notepad
    ' --------------------------------------------------------'
    Option Explicit

    Dim objShell, WshShell
    set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.Run("cmd")
    objShell.AppActivate("Command Prompt")
    WScript.Sleep 500
    objShell.SendKeys "notepad~"
    WScript.Sleep 500
    ' It works
    objShell.SendKeys "% x"
    WScript.Sleep 200
    objShell.SendKeys "% r"
    WScript.Sleep 200
    objShell.SendKeys "%v"
    WScript.Sleep 200
    objShell.SendKeys "s"
    WScript.Sleep 200
    objShell.SendKeys "Algo{Enter}"
    WScript.Sleep 500
    objShell.SendKeys "%{TAB}"
    WScript.Sleep 500
    objShell.SendKeys "dir~"
    WScript.Sleep 500
    'Does not work
    objShell.SendKeys "% es"
    WScript.Sleep 3500
    objShell.SendKeys "{BACKSPACE}{BACKSPACE}Exit~"
    WScript.Sleep 3500
    objShell.SendKeys "%fx"
    WScript.Sleep 500
    objShell.SendKeys "{TAB}~"

    WScript.Quit
    '  End of SendKeys Example Script
```