# How to maximize current command prompt using command

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, dos

In windows I can maximize current window by keyboard shortcut `Alt`+`space` then `x`. When I working on command prompt, can I do same thing using commands (without using shortcuts)?
Simply I need to create a bat file , that make windows maximize after run that.

**Edit:**
I need to do this without restarting the command prompt. because restart lost the content of existing window.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9232308/2152082

Comment: @stephan: absolutely not

Comment: no, not after your edit. Nevertheless, the answer there from Bernard Chen might help you.

Comment: You may be able to send key events through a vbscript using cscript maximize.vbs or similar. However, there is a question regarding sending alt-space to a cmd window that you should read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023509/how-to-send-altspace-to-console-window

Comment: similar to what NC ND posted but implemented in Powershell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993926/maximize-window-and-bring-it-in-front-with-powershell (you'd need to change some details)

Answer (score 1):

I've not found any reliable way of doing it without a third party tool. So, if you have access to a c compiler, you can build your own

```
#define  _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include "windows.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ShowWindow(
        (HWND) GetConsoleWindow(), 
        argc > 1 ? atoi( argv[1] ) : SW_SHOWDEFAULT
    );
    return 0;
}
```

Tested with mingw/gcc. This code uses the [`ShowWindow` api function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to change the show state of the current console window (handle retrieved via `GetConsoleWindow()`). If compiled to `showWindow.exe` you can do

`showWindow.exe 3` to maximize the window

`showWindow.exe 6` to minimize the window

`showWindow.exe` to return to default mode

See the api documentation for the full list of allowed values.

Comment: In theory someone could pinvoke the command in C#, wrap it in powershell, and run from a .bat file without need for an .exe   http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getconsolewindow

Answer (score 0):

i think you'll have to check for additional software like [autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/) or 
[CMDOW](http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/)

Comment: I need to Maximize started window. not to start.